# Grouping the Results of query into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Query is returning 4 records (row), i want to SUM all these records into one record (row) but not entirely sure how to achieve this.

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
    Tax + StudentLoans AS 'Net Income Tax', 
    GrossNI,
    CASE 
        WHEN ed.EA_Indicator_CY = 0 
            THEN 0 
        ELSE 
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN    (
                            SELECT SUM(Funding) 
                            FROM PayrollRuns 
                            WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND PYear = 2018) > 3000
                        ) 
                    THEN 0 
                ELSE 3000 
            END
        ) 
    END AS 'Employment Allowance',
    SMP AS 'SMP Recovered',
    NICompOnSMP AS 'SMP Comp',
    SPPA + SPPB AS 'SPP Recovered',
    SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation AS 'SPP COMP',
    SAP AS 'SAP Recovered',
    SAPCompensation,
    SHPP_A + SHPP_B AS 'Shpp Recovered',
    SHPP_A_Compensation + SHPP_B_Compensation AS 'ShPP Comp',
    Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
FROM PayrollRuns pr
CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND pr.PYear = 2018 --RunID = '1058'
GROUP BY Tax, StudentLoans, GrossNI, SMP, NICompOnSMP, 
    ed.EA_Indicator_CY,
    SPPACompensation, SPPBCompensation, SAPCompensation, SHPP_A_Compensation,
    SHPP_B_Compensation, SPPA, SPPB, SAP, Apprenticeship_Levy_Due, SHPP_A, 
    SHPP_B, RunID
```

I have attached a pic of the results of the query. i want them the sum of them in one row. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read (and to write...)

Comment: @jarlh im quite new to SQL, what is Left justified SQL?

Comment: He is referring to your not using spaces to indent the code. Like I'll edit for you.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Oh ok i see what you mean now. This is how i write all my queries, never realised it was bad practice.

Comment: If you want to only have 1 line, remove from the `GROUP BY` all the fields that have different values in these 3 lines.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **Sum() aggreagtion function** as follows

--If a column is missed, you can add it: put sum(column) [column_alias]

```
select 
sum(mytab.[Net Income Tax]) [sum_Net Income Tax],
sum(mytab.[GrossNI]) [sum_GrossNI],
sum(mytab.[Employment Allowance])[sum_Employment Allowance],
sum(mytab.[SMP Recovered])[sum_SMP Recovered],
sum(mytab.[ShPP Comp]) [sum_ShPP Comp],
sum(mytab.[SPP COMP]) [sum_SPP COMP],
sum(mytab.[App Levy]) [sum_App Levy],
sum(mytab.[SAPCompensation])[sum_SAPCompensation]

from(
SELECT 
    Tax + StudentLoans AS 'Net Income Tax', 
    GrossNI,
    CASE 
        WHEN ed.EA_Indicator_CY = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN    (
                            SELECT SUM(Funding) 
                            FROM PayrollRuns 
                            WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND PYear = 2018) > 3000
                        ) 
                    THEN 0 
                ELSE 3000 
            END
        ) END AS 'Employment Allowance',
    SMP AS 'SMP Recovered',
    NICompOnSMP AS 'SMP Comp',
    SPPA + SPPB AS 'SPP Recovered',
    SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation AS 'SPP COMP',
    SAP AS 'SAP Recovered',
    SAPCompensation,
    SHPP_A + SHPP_B AS 'Shpp Recovered',
    SHPP_A_Compensation + SHPP_B_Compensation AS 'ShPP Comp',
    Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
FROM PayrollRuns pr
CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND pr.PYear = 2018 --RunID = '1058'
GROUP BY Tax, StudentLoans, GrossNI, SMP, NICompOnSMP, 
    ed.EA_Indicator_CY,
    SPPACompensation, SPPBCompensation, SAPCompensation, SHPP_A_Compensation,
    SHPP_B_Compensation, SPPA, SPPB, SAP, Apprenticeship_Levy_Due, SHPP_A, 
    SHPP_B, RunID
) mytab
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what if i just want the Employment Allowance to be what comes back from the CASE WHEN in the SELECT statement? Either 0 or 3000?

Comment: it will be the sum of "employment allowance"

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all the columns in group by which you need to sum up. Try this: Will fetch records grouped by RUNID and having a different EA_Indicator_CY.

```
SELECT SUM(Tax +StudentLoans) AS 'Net Income Tax'
    ,SUm(GrossNI)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (ed.EA_Indicator_CY) = 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE (
                CASE 
                    WHEN (
                            SELECT SUM(Funding)
                            FROM PayrollRuns
                            WHERE PAYEMonth = 12
                                AND PYear = 2018
                            ) > 3000
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE 3000
                    END
                )
        END AS 'Employment Allowance'
    ,SUM(SMP) AS 'SMP Recovered'
    ,SUM(NICompOnSMP) AS 'SMP Comp'
    ,SUM(SPPA + SPPB) AS 'SPP Recovered'
    ,SUM(SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation) AS 'SPP COMP'
    ,SUM(SAP) AS 'SAP Recovered'
    ,SUM(SAPCompensation)
    ,SUM(SHPP_A + SHPP_B) AS 'Shpp Recovered'
    ,SUM(SHPP_A_Compensation) + SUM(SHPP_B_Compensation) AS 'ShPP Comp'
    ,Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
FROM PayrollRuns pr
CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
WHERE PAYEMonth = 12
    AND pr.PYear = 2018 --RunID = '1058'
    group by ed.EA_Indicator_CY,RUNID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum([Net Income Tax]) as [Net Income Tax],sum([GrossNI') as [GrossNI]
,[Employment Allowance] as [Employment Allowance]
,sum([SMP Recovered]) as [SMP Recovered],sum([SMP Comp]) as [SMP Comp]
,sum([SPP Recovered]) as [SPP Recovered],sum([SPP COMP]) as [SPP COMP]
,sum([SAP Recovered]) as [SAP Recovered],sum([SAPCompensation]) as [SAPCompensation]
,sum([Shpp Recovered]) as [Shpp Recovered],sum([ShPP Comp]) as [ShPP Comp]
,sum([App Levy]) as [App Levy]
FROM (  SELECT 
Tax + StudentLoans AS 'Net Income Tax', 
GrossNI,
CASE WHEN ed.EA_Indicator_CY = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN  (SELECT 
SUM(Funding) FROM PayrollRuns WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND PYear = 2018) > 
3000 THEN 0 ELSE 3000 END) END AS 'Employment Allowance',
SMP AS 'SMP Recovered',
NICompOnSMP AS 'SMP Comp',
SPPA + SPPB AS 'SPP Recovered',
SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation AS 'SPP COMP',
SAP AS 'SAP Recovered',
SAPCompensation,
SHPP_A + SHPP_B AS 'Shpp Recovered',
SHPP_A_Compensation + SHPP_B_Compensation AS 'ShPP Comp',
Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
FROM PayrollRuns pr
CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
WHERE PAYEMonth = 12 AND pr.PYear = 2018 --RunID = '1058'
GROUP BY Tax, StudentLoans, GrossNI, SMP, NICompOnSMP, 
ed.EA_Indicator_CY,
SPPACompensation, SPPBCompensation, SAPCompensation, SHPP_A_Compensation,
SHPP_B_Compensation, SPPA, SPPB, SAP, Apprenticeship_Levy_Due, SHPP_A, 
SHPP_B, RunID)
GROUP BY [Employment Allowance]
```

Comment: Please, provide some commentary to your answer.